# TwitterUtils not found after including dependencies in SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I've included the dependencies that *apparently* are the source of the `TwitterUtils` class with the following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.0.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-twitter" % "1.0.0"
)
```

And then in my code file(s), I've included this `import` statement:

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
```

And in the main class, I've tried to use `TwitterUtils`:

```
val tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
```

And I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterUtils$

Does this error indicate that there is an incorrectly installed dependency at the SBT level? or does this mean something else?

Comment: I think it's not the problem with the dependency. If you run `sbt update` and get no errors, the dependencies are downloaded/resolved. Usually you get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when your classes are compiled against a different version of some library. So, try to do `sbt clean` and then `sbt compile`.

Comment: You get this err when you compile or run?

Comment: @giaosudau when I run